# How do I stop my Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

in my little quiz application I created a Thread including a handler that is linked to my progress bar. 
I am not quite sure how to stop the thread at the present position (e.g. 50% progress bar timer) after I clicked an answer button?

This is my code for the Thread so far:

```
private Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (progressStatus < 100) {
            progressStatus++;
            android.os.SystemClock.sleep(50);
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                }
            });
        }
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                questionLabel.setText("Times Up");
                thread.interrupt();
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: As a rule, threads communicate through shared variables.  Change your `while(progressStatus<100)` loop to look at some `volatile boolean` or `AtomicBoolean` variable, and exit when some other thread changes its value.

Comment: Also, as a rule, it's better to use timers to animate a GUI instead of using dedicated threads.